# Phonegap/Cordova: Error while building for android platform

Tags: android, cordova

> phonegap build android

[**phonegap**] adding the Android platform...

[**error**] An error occured during creation of android sub-project.

/Users/MYMacbook/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: The command "android" failed. Make sure you have the latest Android SDK installed, and the "android" command (inside the tools/ folder) is added to your path.

I have the latest sdk updated. yet the error haunts again and again .
Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the error message, it looks like you need to add the Android home tools and platform tools folders to your `$PATH`, i.e.

```
export ANDROID_HOME="/path/to/your/sdk-folder" # e.g. "/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/sdk"
export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools"
```

and then run `source ~/.bash_profile` or `source ~/.profile` based on [which one you used](http://hints.macworld.com/comment.php?mode=view&cid=77069).

Then you'll need to run `phonegap install android` **before** you do `build`.

Finally, it would probably help you to update phonegap/cordova; I'm guessing you have it installed via npm so run ([fix sudo if necessary](http://howtonode.org/introduction-to-npm)):

```
npm cache clean
npm update -g
```

[Android platform guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide) for reference.

Answer (score 3):

it looks like a path issue, so Phonegap CLI scripts cannot reach to the Android toolchain.

Have you followed the Phonegap Android guide [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide)? Most importantly this part:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/Development/adt-bundle/sdk/platform-tools:/Development/adt-bundle/sdk/tools
```

Best.

Answer (score 0):

Using this link, my project built :
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide